# Short trip city car - How often to take it for a highway jaunt to burn off condensation / carbon?

Tags: preventive-maintenance

I live in a very urban area and work remotely. As such my car only gets driven once every week or so and when it is driven, it is usually only to somewhere a few miles away. I know this is not good for the car. How often should I take it on the highway for to warm things up and keep things in good working order? Is once a month enough?

Thanks

Comment: I am interested to learn if there are any good answers for this question.  I can say that I have an *internal combustion engine* powered vehicle that runs fine that hasn't been driven more than 2 or 3 times at highway speeds for several years.  I don't even change the oil every year because it gets driven so little.  I used to be methodical about driving it at highway speeds regularly, but I gave up on that.  Maybe I'm just lucky... I dunno.  The one thing that I have found that makes a difference is to start a vehicle at least once every week or two and get it nice and warmed up.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - You could most likely form that into an answer.

Comment: If your engine doesn't have lots of carbon buildup by now, you are indeed lucky. Some engine designs do run very clean, so keep doing what you're doing.  You might be surprised, however, if you take your car on the open highway and push the pedal down a good way, to find that you have poor acceleration.  Floor the pedal altogether and you'll likely see a cloud of gray smoke in the rear view mirror!

Comment: Infrequent oil changes will definitely cause accelerated engine wear, even if you don't drive much.  Water condensation happens constantly in the crankcase, combining with sulphur gases from combustion to form sulphuric acid.  This acid dissolves metal! Fresh oil has additives to neutralize the acid.  In your case, oil left only three months will become depleted and will not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard-and-fast rule here but if it were mine, I'd try to drive it for an hour or so at least once a week vs. once a month.